# Is there javaToJS/jsToJava api similar to Rhino in J2V8?

Tags: j2v8

It's grateful that you provide so excellent J2V8 framework, I'm embedding it for my
project, My project is now using Rhino engine.
I'm facing one problem.
I found there's no javaToJS or jsToJava api in J2V8, but Rhino has this api.
In our project, we use javaToJS to convert java object to javascript object directly,
it's necessary and convenient api for us.
Therefore, would you do us favor to tell us how to convert java object to javascript in
J2V8, or javascript to java.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we have same goal of migration from `Rhino` to `V8`. 
I have found, that for conversion of *V8* objects to *Java* objects `V8ObjectUtils.getValue()` could be used. Also [TypeAdapter](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eclipsesource/v8/utils/TypeAdapter.java#L18) could be used optionally to provide custom transformation rules if needed.

Unfortunatly V8 does not provide ability to convert *Java* objects to *V8* object.
But I have found nice project, which does it - [v8-adapter](https://github.com/alicorn-systems/v8-adapter)

Also I have added some behaviour to the project, which is similar to Rhino - e.g. read *V8 objects* as *Java maps* or *V8 arrays* as *Java lists* in Java *host* objects. As well as some other enhancements. Thus your migration should be easier now. The v8-adapter project is developed actively - feel free to contribute if something is needed.